# How to filter table item by binding to checkbox ?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some table ( using ListView ) and i want to show in the table some object ( make filter ) if some checkbox is checked ....  ( if the checkbox is not checked i want to show all the table items )

How can i do it by using mvvm ? I can't use the .cs file that bihind the xaml.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a little example how it can works

code at your xaml, bind to the FilterItems property

```
<CheckBox Content="should i filter the view?" IsChecked="{Binding FilterItems}" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollView}" />
```

code behond at your model view

```
public class MainModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainModelView()
    {
        var coll = new ObservableCollection<YourClass>();
        yourCollView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(coll);
        yourCollView.Filter += new Predicate<object>(yourCollView_Filter);
    }

    bool yourCollView_Filter(object obj)
    {
        return FilterItems
            ? false // now filter your item
            : true;
    }

    private ICollectionView yourCollView;
    public ICollectionView YourCollView
    {
        get { return yourCollView; }
        set
        {
            if (value == yourCollView) {
                return;
            }
            yourCollView = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("YourCollView");
        }
    }

    private bool _filterItems;
    public bool FilterItems
    {
        get { return _filterItems; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _filterItems) {
                return;
            }
            _filterItems = value;
            // filer your collection here
            YourCollView.Refresh();
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterItems");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        var eh = PropertyChanged;
        if (eh != null) {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
a complete example is located [here](https://github.com/punker76/sharpdevelop_projects/tree/master/filter_table_item_by_checkbox)

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can bind IsChecked property of checkbox in ViewModel. And in prpoperty setter you can filter your collection which gets binded to ListView.

**XAML:**

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
   get
   {
     return _isChecked; 
   }
   set
   {
     _isChecked = value;
     //filer your collection here
   }
}
```